# Error handling while monitoring log file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, error-handling, logfile

I have a log file that logs the output of a serial port. Once the matched line is found, it terminates the search and continues on with the rest of script.

My problem is sometimes, but not always, there a point when the machine that's being logged through serial halts and waits for user input ("press any key to continue").

Since my current script is only looking for a certain string `Login:`, it doesn't have a way to `echo` a return to bypass the prompt and continue to look for the `Login:` string.

Is there an easy way to add some sort of `case` or `if` statement to the following script?

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 > serial.log &
catPID=$!
sh -c 'tail -n +0 -f serial.log | { sed  "/Login:/ q" && kill $$ ;}' &
searchPID=$!
wait "$searchPID"
kill "$catPID"
echo "Admin" > /dev/ttyS0
```

I need a way for the script to check if the string: `Press any key to continue`, then `echo \r` and if it doesn't happen to prompt, continue searching for the `Login:` prompt.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are actually trying to do here but this sounds like the sort of thing you might want to use [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Etan told you, this is a job for the `expect`. If you can't or don't have expect, here is an poor-man-expect alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash
fromserial() {
    cat /dev/ttyS0
}

to_serial() {
    echo -en "$@" > /dev/ttyS0
}

#fromserial | tee logfile | while :     #if want logfile
while :                    #if not
do
    read -r -t1 line
    case "$line" in
        Login:) to_serial "Admin" ; exit ;;
        '') ;; #nothing
        'Press any key to continue') to_serial "\r" ;;
    esac
done < <(fromserial)
```

Comment: this mostly works, but the `read` doesn't seem to exit after the loop has ended. but when I `echo "anything" > /dev/ttyS0` after the `Login:` is echoed it finally exits. why is it not exiting after the `case` exits. @jm666

Comment: @BenTech2 Maybe, because the `fromserial | while` runs in the subshell. try now - edited. Anyway, it is strange, because exits for me when trying `bash script`  (using an random `fromserial` function)... Modified you somewhat the script?

Comment: Thanks, that did it. changed `exit` to `break` to make  the script continue after the `case` was complete.

Comment: @BenTech2 so you want continue - ok - sometimes didn't unserstand everything, my english is not the best...